# JSON и DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable

Есть JSON объект , задача распарсить и закинуть содержимое в таблицу.

```
var restore = [
{
"name": "Блок 1. Участие в деятельности органов студенческого самоуправления и социальная работа",
"subblock": [{ "name": "Блок 1.1. Студенческая организация (СО)",
"paragraph": [{ "name": "Председатель СО университета"}, { "score": "10,00"}, { "name": "Заместители председателя СО университета"}, { "score": "9, 00 "}]}]
}
];
```

Пытаюсь закинуть это в таблицу

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( 
    {
      data:restore,
       "columns": [
            { data:"subblock[0].paragraph[0].name" },
            { data:"subblock[0].paragraph[0].score"}
        ]

    });

}) ;
```

В итоге получаю в ячейках такие значение - **Председатель СО университета 00Заместитель председателя СО университетa0** вместо **Председатель СО университета Заместитель председателя СО университетa**. 
Есть мнение что шалит кодировка. В самом доке стоит `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: "Есть мнение что шалит кодировка." - так попробуйте данные с латиницей.

Comment: Пробовал, тоже самое

Answer (score 0):

Уберите нулевые индексы:

```js
var restore = [{
  "name": "Блок 1. Участие в деятельности органов студенческого самоуправления и социальная работа",
  "subblock": [{
    "name": "Блок 1.1. Студенческая организация (СО)",
    "paragraph": [{
      "name": "Председатель СО университета"
    }, {
      "score": "10,00"
    }, {
      "name": "Заместители председателя СО университета"
    }, {
      "score": "9, 00 "
    }]
  }]
}];

$('#example').DataTable({
  data: restore,
  "columns": [{
      data: "subblock[].paragraph[].name"
    },
    {
      data: "subblock[].paragraph[].score"
    }
  ]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" border=1><table>
```

Comment: Уже лучше ,но теперь же все записи вложенного обьекта выводятся в одну ячейку.

Comment: @ТарасДанальченко Я не понимаю, как Вы хотите распределить данные из `restore` по записям/ячейкам.

Comment: С бэка приходят данные в формате JSON , которые нужно распихать в таблицу . Приходят такие данные block:name (условно говоря caption), вложенный объект subblock:name ( под видом <tr>
                    <th colspan="4">Блок 1.3. Профбюро</th>
                </tr>) и вложенный объект subblock`a - paragraph с параметрами name , score . Сейчас стоит проблема что бы правильно разместить обьекты paragraph в таблице